# bash IRC bot easiest way to get user mode for channel

Tags: bash, while-loop, bots, irc

I have wrote a bash bot for IRC which uses `tail -f file | nc irc.server.org | while read string` to connect & talk to the IRC server.

The problem im having is that I would like to check what the users mode is in the channel the bot joins, eg (+ voice, @ OP) etc.

The 1 way I have found to get this info are by `/NAMES #channel` which is not ideal since I have to wait for a response and then run another loop of the while loop before I can process the response

Another thing I would like to do is see if the user has authenticated against nickserv, I can do this by sending the message `NICKSERV STATUS Username`, but yet again I need to wait for a response.

Comment: The bot should be able to get the usermodes from the network status page upon joining a channel.

Comment: wouldn't life be easy if they could just add that to the user message string

Comment: This is not really an answer, so I put it in comment, but if you want to make an IRC bot with bash, I strongly recommand you to use this tool: http://tools.suckless.org/ii/ , it's an IRC client that use Unix file system to communicate. If you want to build a bot with it, you just have to read/write into files

Comment: so with ii will I be able to receive a `!command` from the user, then do a lookup to see if they are registered, get a response & then reply with the correct output?

Comment: @l'L'l I followed your advice & captured the user list upon joining the channel & then the chanserv message on the Auto Voice/OP/etc use modes, tnx :)

Comment: @Sayajin: nice, I'm glad the tip helped - it seems like the most simple solution :) Feel free to post that as an answer and accept it, or let me know and I'll write one up; entirely up to you.